# jquery ajax - update using checkbox doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I want to create a real time job list. so when adding a new list it will increase in real time or when the job is finished then the user can be checked the list in real time. so other users who are connected in my website will know in real time without refresh page.

[image]

so far the addition of a list of jobs works fine, but when doing a checked does not work. the function is checked if it does it under 1 second. when it is checked, the status of the job list will be updated to 1 using php code.
but the problem is the checkbox doesnt work.

here is my html code:

```
  <div class="container-todolist">


          <ul class="todo-list">
            <?php foreach ($tampiltodolist as $list): ?>


            <li class="<?php if ($list['status']==='1') {
              echo " checked";
            }else {
              echo " notchecked";
            } ?>">
              <!-- drag handle -->
              <span class="handle">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                  </span>
              <!-- checkbox -->
              <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" <?php if ($list['status']==='1') {
                echo "checked";
              } ?> name="status" value="<?php echo $list['nolist']; ?>">
              <!-- todo text -->
              <span class="text"><?php echo $list['isi']; ?></span>
              <!-- Emphasis label -->
              <small class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                <?php $tanggal=$list['tanggal'];
                  $waktu =$list['waktu'];
                echo time_elapsed_string("$tanggal $waktu");
               ?>
              </small>
              <!-- General tools such as edit or delete-->
              <div class="tools">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
              </div>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </ul>

            </div>
```

here is my javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        const urlList="<?php echo site_url('Todolist/NewtodoList') ?>";
      $(document).ready(function(){
        const url="<?php echo site_url('Todolist/Addtodolist') ?>";
        const urlList="<?php echo site_url('Todolist/NewtodoList') ?>";
        const urlCheck ="<?php echo site_url('Todolist/checkedlist') ?>";

        $('#formtodolist').on('submit',function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$('#isi-text').val()) {
      $('#isi-text').addClass('isInValid');
    }else {
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:url,
      data:$(this).serialize(),
      success:function(data){
        $('#todolist').modal('hide');
        $('#isi-text').removeClass('isInValid'),
        $('#isi-text').val('');

      },
    })
    }
    });
    //$('#checkbox').on('click',function(){
    $('input:checkbox').on('change',function(){
    const checkdata= $(this).val();

      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {

        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:urlCheck,
          data:{"checkdata":checkdata},
          success(function(data){
            $('.container-todolist').load(urlList);
          })
        });
      }
    });


      });
      function updateList(){
          $('.container-todolist').load(urlList);

      }

      setInterval('updateList()',1000);

    </script>
```

Comment: you are handling checkbox with id, it is not triggering  other check box. only triggering single checkbox.

Comment: i tired with this code but still doesnt work $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click',function(){

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should update the selector:

```
$(document).on('change','input:checkbox',function(){
const checkdata= $(this).val();

  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {

    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:urlCheck,
      data:{"checkdata":checkdata},
      success(function(data){
        $('.container-todolist').load(urlList);
      })
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change',function(){
        const checkdata= $(this).val();

          if ($(this).prop('checked')) {

            $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url:urlCheck,
              data:{"checkdata":checkdata},
              success(function(data){
                $('.container-todolist').load(urlList);
              })
            });
          }
        });
```

Comment: weired,  what is the value in 'checkdata', why are you setting it as constant ?. check value there

Comment: the value in checkdata is nolist

Comment: That is strange. Should be either true/false.

Comment: what you get in your success function ?